# @nuxt/i18n installation/configuration issue

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I tried to install `@nuxt/i18n` on my project but it doesn't work. I executed the command `npm install @nuxtjs/i18n` without problems. Then I added some lines of code in my `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```
['@nuxtjs/i18n', {
    locales: [
        {
            code: 'it',
            iso: 'it-IT',
            file: 'it-IT.js'
        }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'it'
}]
```

And in `tsconfig.json` I added this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
        "@nuxt/types",
        "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    ]
}
```

Now, when I build the solution, I obtain this error:

```
Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
at _default (____________/node_modules/@nuxtjs/i18n/src/index.js:13:92)
at installModule (____________/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:9)
at async initNuxt (____________/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1823:7)
at async load (____________/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6779:9)
at async Object.invoke (____________/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6840:5)
at async _main (____________/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)
```

I followed the guide at this link: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/setup

Problem persist also without `locales` and `defaultLocale`. What's wrong with my configuration? What is missing?

Comment: My guess would be that it's an incompatibility between your version of Nuxt and the one of the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `i18n` configuration to your plugin folder (`/plugins/i18n.ts`).

Here is one example of plugin configuration

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
    const i18n = createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        globalInjection: true,
        locale: 'it',
        messages: {
            en: {
                test: 'Hello, {name}!'
            },
            it: {
                test: 'Ciao, {name}!'
            }
        }
    })

    vueApp.use(i18n)
})
```

your `nuxt.config.ts` file should look like this:

```
modules: [
        ...
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
        ...
],
```

to use your labels in template you can use the following syntax:

```html
<h1>{{ $t('test', { name: 'vue-i18n' }) }}</h1>
```

if you need more details you chan check this [articl](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/integrations/nuxt3.html#localize-your-nuxt-3-application).

Comment: You can also check this issue: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/i18n/issues/2393

Answer (score -1):

You need to add "vue-i18n" module...use i18n via plugin...follow this doc:- https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/integrations/nuxt3.html

Comment: I don't see the point of this answer, while the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74773071/8816585) is already precise and well-written. Please put in some effort if you want to help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34749004)